# Where is the meteor MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I create a meteor app, where is the database?

I have an app called leaderboard, but when I run mongo shell and do `show dbs` I see only `local (empty)` and `test` but test doesn't doesn't have the same contents as my leaderboard app. Where does meteor create the Mongo database and how can I access it from mongo shell (so I can load some data into it)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to be running the application with the meteor run command in one session, at which point you can run mongo meteor in another session on the same machine, which will include something like

```
[kfullert@shotgun ]$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
```

At that point, you can use the URL in the "connecting to" line with the standard mongo tools (caveat - you need to be running your project with meteor at the same time, as "meteor run" is what spins up the mongo server for your project

```
[kfullert@shotgun ]$ mongo 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
>
```

For mongoimport, you'll probably want something like:

```
[kfullert@shotgun ]$ mongoimport -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3002 -d meteor
```

Additionally, it may be possible to run mongoimport without meteor running, by using the following switch from your project root directory (untested so beware)

```
mongoimport --dbpath .meteor/local/db -d meteor
```

Comment: is it possible to run mongodb on the web browser?

Comment: meteor automatically runs minimongo (a lite, js version) in the browser, but you still need a server-side version mongodb for data sharing between clients

Answer (score 8):

For apps running a local db server, APPDIR/.meteor/local/db

Comment: This correctly answers the main question but the OP then asked a second question which is what the other responses deal with.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer to the asked question.

Answer (score 7):

You can connect to your app's mongodb with [`meteor mongo`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteormongo) and then us `show collections` to list the `Meteor.Collection`s you've created.

Comment: do you know how I can run `mongoimport` against it? specifically trying to import a csv `mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline` into my meteor database. can do it with a database which is not under meteor, but not able to do it with a meteor db.

Comment: is there any other way? I can't run `mongoimport` from that shell.

Comment: `mongoimport` isn't used from that shell. You need to download the full mongodb kit from 10gen @ mongodb.org and use the `mongoimport` utility , usually in the `bin` folder