# how to use mongoimport with my meteor application database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm able to use `mongoimport` to import csv data into a non-meteor mongodb database, but I can't figure out how to import a csv into my meteor app database.

I learned how to run the mongo shell for my meteor app (`meteor mongo`) but I can't run `mongoimport` from the shell.

The mongodb docs for `mongoimport` says

> In this example, mongoimport imports the csv formatted data in the /opt/backups/contacts.csv into the collection contacts in the users database on the MongoDB instance running on the localhost port numbered 27017.
>
> mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv

But when I run `mongod`, start my meteor app, and run `mongoimport` it imports to my `test` database, not my app database.

I read this stackoverflow post comment:

> Use mongoexport to dump your collections individually, then mongoimport to import the files into the db named meteor in the meteor mongodb instance. The meteor mongo instance runs on port 3002 with bind_address 127.0.0.1, and the data files are in the meteor project subdirectory .meteor/local/db

But I don't understand how to connect to that instance or how to target it with the `mongoimport` command.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like I just answered your comment in [Rahuls wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363710/where-is-the-metoer-monogodb-database). Anyway download mongodb from mongodb.org for your OS (or a package manager like macports) and use the tool provided in the bin folder. `mongoimport` isn't a command in the mongo shell, it's an executable that runs separately.

Also don't forget to put the port in (usually *3001* if you're running your meteor instance at *3000*), also the db is usually *meteor* & not *users* when you run it

```
mongoimport -h localhost:3001 --db meteor --collection contacts --type csv --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Comment: the strangest thing keeps happening. I import the data as you say, into a collection called `kanji`. But from meteor I get an error that `kanji is undefined` when I query it. If I insert into it from meteor js code I can read my inserted record back. Not sure where the mongoimport records went, but they are not in my meteor db.

Comment: It doesn't look like it went into your meteor db, use a tool like MongoHUB https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac to help you check, I noticed you used `users` for your db instead of `meteor` did you try changing it?

Comment: Konichiwa! Also you need to still use `var kanji= new Meteor.Collection('kanji');` on your client and server js if you haven't already done so. Meteor won't check for collections unless you tell it to

Comment: I tried to approve your edit but it wouldn't let me someone else got to it first, `-h` or `--host` would work

Comment: Arigatou!  OK yes after I explicited made the collection in meteor, then did the mongoimport it seemed to connect. weird. This stuff isn't always very intuitive!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: bonus points! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367426/find-in-a-javascript-array-from-meteor-mongodb

Comment: Don't forget to add --jsonArray if your input is a json array.

Comment: This is weird. I keep getting an error: `bash: /usr/local/bin/mongoimport: cannot execute binary file`. Meteor is running.

Comment: Wow. Trying to execute 64-bit on a 32-bit. *slaps self*

Comment: I ran into some errors related to the port that meteor was running mongo on. But if you just run `meteor mongo` the intro text will tell you which port it is using. "connecting to: 127.0.0.1:30001/meteor" for instance. They you can use that in your mongoimport command.

Answer (score 8):

NOTE:  The above method did NOT work on port 3002 for me, but it DID work on port 3001.

To import a external TSV file into a meteor db, I started the meteor app needing the TSV data.  This also launches the meteor mongodb service (in my case on host: localhost:3001), then I opened a terminal in OSX and via the terminal, navigated to a mongodb package bin folder, which I downloaded earlier in order to get the binary, "mongoimport".  Once in the bin folder of the mongodb package, then at the command prompt I typed the following below (some switch options will vary...but --host, --localhost and --db switch/values should be as shown):

```
$  ./mongoimport --host localhost:3001 --db meteor --collection datarefs --type tsv --drop --headerline --file /PathToFile/DataRefs.tsv
```

After hitting enter, mongoimport echo'd successful import in the terminal.  Once this was done, I could navigate to the meteor app via the terminal and launch meteor mongo: $meteor mongo....and see the imported collection, "datarefs" in the meteor db for this app.

```
$  meteor mongo
...
...
meteor:PRIMARY> show collections
datarefs
system.indexes
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: You could also install `mongo` via `homebrew` and `mongoimport` will be available

Answer (score 4):

First create collection in meteor app  like this

```
Students = new Meteor.Collection("students");
```

Then add some dummy value to be sure meteor initialized collection

`Students.insert({"name":"first"});`

In some click event for example.
To check use this

`meteor:PRIMARY> show collections
students
system.indexes`

Then import.
 `mongoimport -h localhost:3001 -d meteor -c students < students.json`

Somehow meteor doesn't recognize new imported collections you need either remove all of them add some dummy value then import again or create new one and initialize it with dummy value and then import.There might be binding bug because collections show up right in minimongo.

Thank you  to Akshat and Tom Kyler

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because I had not initialized the collection via Meteor before loading the data with mongoimport. Nothing showed up until I initialized the collection and THEN loaded the data.

Answer (score 0):

A small script (template) for running mongoimport to xxx.meteor.com

```
    #!/bin/sh

    # Script to import csvfile to meteor application deployed to free meteor.com hosting.
    # Make sure your versions of mongo match with the metor.com mongo versions. 
    # As Jan 2016 it seems to be 3.x something. Tested with mongoimport 3.12.

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
      then
        echo "usage: $0 xxx.meteor.com collection filename.csv"
        exit 1
    fi

    URL=$1
    COLLECTION=$2
    FILE=$3

    echo Connecting to $URL, please stand by.... collection=$COLLECTION file=$FILE

    PUPMS=`meteor mongo --url $URL | sed 's/mongodb:\/\// -u /' | sed 's/:/ -p /' | sed 's/@/ -h /'  | sed 's/\// -d /'`



    mongoimport -v $PUPMS --type csv --headerline --collection $COLLECTION  --file $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I use [mongochef](http://3t.io/mongochef/) to move data between databases. It's very easy--you just connect to each database (usually local and remote db) then you can copy and paste documents across collections. Much easier than the command-line approach.