# find in a javascript array from meteor mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

this works

```js
Template.kanjifinder.kanjicharacters = function () {
    console.log("kanjlist");
    return kanji.find({cardid: {$in:[1,2]}}, {sort: {cardid: 1}});  
};
```

but is there a way to replace this hardcoded array `[1,2]` with a javascript array?

```js
var str = "123456"
var cardids = str.split("");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.kanjifinder.kanjicharacters = function () {
        console.log("kanjlist");
        return kanji.find({cardid: {$in: **cardids** }}, {sort: {cardid: 1}});  
    } 
};
```

Comment: What does the document in your kanji collection look like?

Comment: well i'm just using `cardid` here as a test. Ultimately I'll be trying to find Japanese kanji characters instead of the cardid numbers. But I don't want to get bogged down in utf-8 issues for the moment. Basically : `cardid: 9
kanji: "中"
volume: "Series 2 Volume 1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a separator in your string, you could do it that way in your code too, but the problem is 2 digit numbers:

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6" //<<--- use a seperator here
var cardids = str.split(","); //<<--

//remove this line if you intend to use strings in your db instead of integers
cardids = _.map(function(card) { return parseInt(card);});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
   Template.kanjifinder.kanjicharacters = function () {
     console.log("kanjlist");
     return kanji.find({cardid: {$in:cardids}}, {sort: {cardid: 1}});  
   };
}
```

I'm using underscore to convert the strings to integers, if you don't already have it add it to your meteor package with `meteor add underscore`

Comment: without the separator you just get a character array (which is what I want). as I wrote it console.log(cardids) = `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] `. But when I put cardid: {$in:cardids}} i get no results.

Comment: I see, the above are strings and mongodb has integers, do you have underscore in your package?

Comment: is it a type issue? i.e. $in doesn't like looking for a number in a string?

Comment: Ok I'll just try it with the kanji instead of numbers. strings-to-string is my ultimate goal here anyway. just a moment.

Comment: Ive edited it to use integers too, that map function will convert the strings to integers

Comment: correction. I had the wrong field name. now it's all working perfect. Thanks for help me so much with my trial-by-fire! I'm making progress with my private hackathon