# How to import csv in meteor mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm facing a problem in importing a CSV file to my db. I tried this command:

```
mongoimport --db meteor -h localhost:3001 -c TollPlaza -d meteor --headerline --type csv --file TollPlaza.csv
```

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365747/how-to-use-mongoimport-with-my-meteor-application-database) but am still  having a problem.

Comment: What's the nature of the problem? An error? Incorrect data being imported?

Comment: What problem? Are you running your application and therefore the server when doing this? Have you confirmed the server is being run on port `3001`. Check to see whhat port the server is running on with `ps aux | grep mongod`

Answer (score -1):

Try this query  :

> mongoimport --db meteor --host localhost --port 3001 -c TollPlaza -d
>   meteor --headerline --type csv --file TollPlaza.csv

Maybe seperate  host and port

Comment: This is just a copy of what the OP says they are already doing in their question and does not attempt to address the possible issues.

Answer (score -1):

The query is perfectly fine.

Follow the instructions

1. run the meteor project
2. Open a one more command prompt in same location
3. make sure that csv file present in the same directory.
4. run the query.
5. check the DB (show collections).